# Powershell remote file search on servers on multiple drives

Tags: powershell, search, remote-server

So i have a very simple powershell command that is looking for a specific file extension on a remote server.  These remote servers have multiple logical drives (c:,e:,d: ect...) and when i run this command it works against the C: drive of the server but any drives afterwards return a single error Get-ChildItem : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'D' does not exist.

Command is this, any help is appreciated:

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName chsccm10 win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType = 3" | Select-Object DeviceID | ForEach-Object {Get-ChildItem ($_.DeviceID + "\") -Include *.log -Recurse } | select VersionInfo
```

Comment: You're trying to run the results of the search against your local machine! I'd bet that you don't have a drive `D:` locally. You need to combine the results with an `Invoke-Command` or some other remoting.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested, but maybe something like this:

```
$servers = gc c:\serverlist.txt

$results = $servers | %{
    invoke-command -cn $_  -scriptblock {
            gwmi win32_logicaldisk -filter "DriveType = 3" |
            select-object DeviceID |
            Foreach-object {
                Get-childitem ($_.DeviceID + "\") -include *.log -recurse } |
            select VersionInfo}}

$results | out-gridview
```